# how to call function every 2 mins

Tags: angularjs

how to call a save function every two mins in anular js. please Help me.

```
 $scope.save = function () {
        $http({
        url : '/api/products',
        method : "POST",
         },
        data : $scope.product,          
    }).success(function (data) {}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use setInteraval function to call your function every 120000 milliseconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $scope.save();
}, 120000)
```

Comment: You should use $interval service instead of setInterval.

Comment: Do you know how to use  $interval service. to start and stop after 2mins

Comment: To stop interval, you can use `$interval.cancel(promise)`, you also can stop interval after several iterations with `$interval(fn, delay, count)` where `count` is number of iterations. More inforamtion [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval)

Comment: If you are using Angular (as stated in the question), you need to use the `$interval` service. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31889571/114558

Comment: Note that in OP's specific use-case, `setInterval()` probably works, but if using Angular, you should get into the habit of using `$interval` instead.

Answer (score 20):

You could try using the [$interval service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

In case you need something more accurate, consider using an external library.

Comment: Your link has a couple extra characters and goes nowhere. I think you mean to go here?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. I guess they changed their url scheme at some point.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following way also.

Declaring the interval:

```
var interval = null;
```

To cancel interval:

```
if (interval != null)

    $interval.cancel(interval);
```

Call the function as per as interval:

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.function();
}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use $interval from angularjs

```
setInterval(function(){
  $scope.save();
}, 120000)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use setInteraval function.

```
 setInterval(function(){
 $scope.save();
 }, 120000)
```