# Difference between $interval and setInterval in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between $interval and setInterval.
I have this test:

```
Dashboard.prototype.updateTotalAppointments = function(){
//console.log();
this.appointmentsCount = this.appointmentsCount +1;
console.log(this.appointmentsCount);
};

Dashboard.prototype.start = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        this.updateTotalAppointments();
    }.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

>

```
div class="hb-info-card-data-count"><h1>{{dashCtrl.appointmentsCount}}</h1></div>
```

Using **setInterval** doesn't update the value on the HTML page, but the value actually changes on the browser console, but it just doesn't get updated on the Html page.

but if i do this :

```
Dashboard.prototype.start = function(){
$interval(function(){//using $interval seems to work fine
    this.updateTotalAppointments();
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

}

This seems to work perfectly, so i really don't know why the latter didn't work,
but i would really like to know please.

And also what will be the best way to constantly request data from the background lets say every n-minutes and update the page via its controller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) is Angular's wrapper for the native Javascript setInterval.

When `$interval` is used, Angular is aware of any scope changes made by the interval function, and the two-way binding reflects the changes.

When `setInterval` is used, Angular will not be aware of any scope changes made by the setInterval function.

Put simply, the `$interval` function triggers Angular's digest cycle while `setInterval` does not.

[This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ddnpTQxjBXHnEWfSqg5w?p=preview) demonstrates the difference.

Code:

```
angular.module('DemoApp', [])
  .controller('IntervalCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {


    var updateExampleText = function() {
      console.log('Changing exampleText');
      $scope.exampleText = 'Time: ' + new Date().getSeconds();
    };

    $scope.useInterval = function() {
      //Show current seconds value 5 times after every 1000 ms
      $interval(updateExampleText, 1000, 5);

    };

    $scope.useSetInterval = function() {
      //$scope.exampleText changes are not reflected in the page
      //because Angular is not aware of the changes.
      setInterval(updateExampleText, 1000);
    };
  });
```

Comment: "When $interval is used, Angular is aware of any scope changes made by the interval function". *Exactly*. +1

Comment: Thanks, This clarifies my doubt, at least i know what i'm doing now, but the angular documentation is :( ....

Answer (score 1):

$interval is a wrap for setInterval AND $apply simultaneous. It make the update of scoped variables to be visible when occours on $interval. Also valid for $timeout