# Moving marker using interval

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, setinterval

I'm making a "simple" program which will simulate a car fleet tracker.
I have the backend (MySQL + Spring) but no connecitons. But that doesn't matter.

I need to know how to move a marker using interval. 
For example: My marker will move "latitude + 0.00005" every 1 second.
Where do i place the function that will increment the latitude of marker and it will be called every second.

this is the code that initializes the map and places a marker which i want to move

```
map.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MouseEvent } from '@agm/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import {timeInterval} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  latitude = 52.2330653;
  longitude = 20.9211119;
  locationChosen = false;

  mapClicked($event: MouseEvent){
    this.markers.push({
      lat: $event.coords.lat + 0.0000005,
      lng: $event.coords.lng
    });
  }


  markers: marker[] = [
    {
      lat: 52.2330600,
      lng: 20.92111,
      label: 'WE228GL',
    }
  ]



  onChoseLocation(event){
    this.latitude = event.coords.lat;
    this.longitude = event.coords.lng;
    this.locationChosen = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
interface marker{
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  label?: string;
}
```

and the html file

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" (mapClick)="onChoseLocation($event)">

  <agm-marker
    *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
    (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
    [latitude]="m.lat"
    [longitude]="m.lng"
    [label]="m.label">


  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I'm stuck. Please help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21251688/1531971

Comment: i know its trelated. but i don't know how to use it unfortunately

Comment: You should try it and see. Read up on `setInterval` or "interval service" and give it a try. The notion is that you have some chunk of code that is run on a schedule. Your job is define this code, and write the set-up and tear-down code that starts and stops the timed task. There are lots of docs and tutorials when you do a web search for "angular interval service"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call function every 2 mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251688/how-to-call-function-every-2-mins)